# Animating item in recyclerview outside of parent

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I'm trying to animate a view in recyclerview outside of its parent,

I have added animation on image click which is in recyclerview.

Please note that the animation is working but the animation is not visible outside the single item layout of the recycler view.

I tried to make all the parent enabled = false

```
   public static void setAllParentsClip(View v, boolean enabled) {
    while (v.getParent() != null && v.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup) {

        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
        viewGroup.setClipChildren(enabled);
        viewGroup.setClipToPadding(enabled);
        viewGroup.setClipToOutline(enabled);
        v = viewGroup;
    }
}
```

But not give what I'm looking for

I also tried to add

```
   android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

for all the Parent but the same result

Comment: Are you sure you are making this on all your parent views (your item in the recyclerview, and also your recyclerview) ... I'm not sure of this, but I think your parent view (item in the adapter) needs to allow it's child views to go out of it's bounds, and the same should be for it's parent as well

Comment: Yes I'm sure, in addition to each view in layout but noting happening and also the setAllParentsClip() fun take the view and make all the its parent  (setClipChildren false)

Comment: I'm having a similar issue while animating the height (classic collapse / expand which changes the top margin of the item).
It's fine when the item is fully visible, it's also fine when the two state of the constraint are outside the visible area of the recycler view.
But it's not working when the collapsed state is fully visible and the expanded state cannot be fully visible. At least that's why I'm guessing without any solution.
Also tried the clipping things without any success.